# VLookup formula in Excel getting wrong answers

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to get some cells from a column to matchup in one of my sheets, however they get completely different answers than they should. I've made 2 exact same formulas, one which was a test and works, and the other one that I need to get working but doesn't work:

I can't post images because of 10 needed reputation but following link shows the problem:

http://gyazo.com/23ce860234ad74b7c287e638c64d5d2f

Notice that I'm swedish, therefore the "LETAUPP" instead of "VLOOKUP". The first formula works perfectly and get's the right numbers each time. However the second picture gets a number that doesn't match. You can see the correct numbers in F1 and F2 for "Upplands Väsby" and "Vallentuna". The numbers they get now are on row 270, matching with "Dorotea". How come they don't get "0114" and "0115" as they should?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the VLOOKUp formula is:

```
=VLOOKUP("Fontana",B2:E7,2,[TRUE/FALSE])
```

You should specify either **true** or **false** in your formulas. If you want to get the exact values you should add **false** to your formula, [examples](http://blog.laptopmag.com/excel-2013-vlookup).